# org.postgresql.util.PGobject not available in org.postgresql

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot 2.1.5.RELEASE and I have the following dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

But `org.postgresql.util.PGobject` is not found. In another non-spring boot project  I have the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

and `org.postgresql.util.PGobject` is available for use.

Any idea why `org.postgresql.util.PGobject` is not found in the spring boot project?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you set the `Postgresql` JDBC driver in the [`runtime`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) scope , which has the following behaviour :

> This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for
>   compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test
>   classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

It is not in the compile classpath causing its class cannot be found during compile. You should change it to `compile` scope , which is the default scope so you can simply leave out `<scope>` :

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```